# Intersection between lines and surface

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a cylinder and some lines. I want to know which lines intersects (go through) the surface of cylinder. How can i do that?

I have tried on creating the cylinder with plot_surface() and lines with plot projection3D. I have tried also on view_init for differents view but it doesn't work.

```py
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax=fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d') 

#plot lines     
for i in range(0,len(inter)):
    id=inter[i]
    X=[]
    Y=[]
    Z=[]
    for j in range(0,len(cable[id])):
        X.append(cable[id][j][0])
        Y.append(cable[id][j][1])
        Z.append(cable[id][j][2])

    ax.plot3D(X,Y,Z,linewidth=1,label=id)
    ax.legend()

#plot cynlinder 
surf=ax.plot_surface(X_cdg, Y_cdg, Z_cdg,color='green',alpha=0.5)
surf.set_edgecolors('green')
```

Only the contour of cylinder have an effect 3D, the lines (from 101 to 105) seems like 2D. So i don't know if its intersects with cylinder.

You can see my results here : https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/25/3/1560933540-2-detec-cable.png

Comment: Why don't you simply evaluate the formula to check if the line intersects the surface? From my experience, it will be much easier than trying to get the coordinates of intersection from the plot.

Comment: not a big deal to transfer it to the python, do you have a general mathematical representation of that formula?

Comment: I'm trying to valide my code in fortran just by making a visualation 3D in python. Im not trying to get the coordinates of intersection in python, just a visualation for a presentation

Comment: ok, so the question is about how to visualise and add the points of intersection on the plot image?

Comment: can you please share the values of `inter` ?

Comment: to check if the line intersects the surface, i do f(x).f(x+1)<0, with x et x+1 is two points on line, f is equation of a plan of cylinder's axe

Comment: i just need to visualise if the lines intersect the cylinder. inter=[101,102,103,104,105] is lines ID